# Build MonoTouch .NET libraries on Windows

Tags: build, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a project of which I want to develop (and build/release to internal nuget) on Windows. There are multiple versions of my assembly (NET40, NET20, etc) that are created as part of my build process.

**I have a new project that wishes to use my libraries on Mono and MonoTouch. Is it possible to build libraries on Windows that are ready to run on MonoTouch/MAC?** Note that I do not wish to program against any MonoTouch.dll or Apple/iOS specific libraries. My assemblies are strictly .NET libraries.

Is changing my target framework to .NET 4.0 "Client Profile" sufficient to get support on Mono platforms (including MonoTouch/iOS)?

Comment: Portable Libraries are what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use portable class library's to do this. [there is a great article on how to get this set up](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/cross-platform-winrt-monodroid.html).

It is quite easy to get set up thanks to the great write up by @slodge on twitter.

Comment: The basic approach works. The binaries generated are in some cases ok to use cross platform... Eg like i have done with json.net :) ... But actually, for using the code in monotouch, I'm currently still recommending you rebuild the pcls against mt - its setup (still .net v2 inside?) and quirks are subtly different - so it's just safer and quicker to rebuild. Sorry if this is confusing (it's confusing and confounding me too)

Comment: More info - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html?m=1